# Infinite Volume $\implies$ Infinite Cross-section

Tags: geometry

Can one prove that if one has some geometric object in 3D Euclidean space (i.e. $\mathbb{R}^3$) and it has infinite volume, then it must have at least one cross-section that has infinite area?

Comment: I think it is not true

Comment: It doesn't seem true in 2D. The area under $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x > 1$ is infinite yet each vertical line segment above any given value of $x$ is finite. It seems like something analogous to this would work for 3D.

Comment: There's an infinite horizontal line (or ray) though. There is no finite x such that 1/x = 0, so x=0 and 1/x don't have an intersection. Thus y = 0 (x > 1) is infinitely long (and a ray).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

Consider, for example, the union of all unit balls with centers on the curve $(t,t^2,t^3)$. This curve's perpendicular distance from an *arbitary* plane $ax+bx+cx=d$ is a non-constant polynomial in $t$, so the intersection between the tube and the plane is bounded (and thus finite).

Comment: Amazing! Thanks very much!

Comment: Might I ask why the perpendicular distance being a non-constant polynomial implies that the intersection is finite?

Comment: @IskyMathews: The value of a nonconstant polynomial diverges to infinity as $t\to\pm\infty$. So there is a bounded intervals of $t$s where the perpendicular distance is $\le 1$. This bounded interval corresponds to a bounded volumethat $(t,t^2,t^3)$ can be in.